# While loop not breaking when condition met

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, break

I have a python code that tries to guess the user's age by asking some questions.
The thing is that when the user's age equals to the variable the while loop won't break. Here's my code:

```
age = 50
guess = raw_input("Give your age: ")
while guess != age:
  print "Are you above ",age,"?"
  x = raw_input()
  while (x != "yes") and (x != "YES") and (x != "no") and (x != "NO"):
    print "Answer with yes/YES, no/NO"
    x = raw_input()
  if (x == "yes") or (x == "YES"):
    age = 2*age-age/2
  else:
    age = age/2

  if age == guess:
    break

print "Your age is ",age
```

Comment: `guess` is a string; convert it to an integer: `guess = int(raw_input("Give your age: ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `int`, raw_input returns a string so you are comparing a `string` to an `int` which will never evaluate to  True:

```
guess = int(raw_input("Give your age: "))

age == guess:
^^      ^^^
int     str
```

Nor sure what a lot of the rest of the code is doing but you can use `in` to replace the and's:

```
while x not in  {"yes","YES","no", "NO"}:
```

Yo also don't need parens in your if statements:

```
if  x == "yes" or x == "YES":
```

Comment: @TheodoreGlampedakis, no worries, I presume this is bisection search?

Comment: @TheodoreGlampedakis, I will leave the rest to you so ;) You should probably rename some variables thought as they are a little confusing

Comment: Yeap will do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define break condition each time you loop through.

In your code you define `guess` only once. So its value will not change.

Please add `guess` in while loop so its value changed and you will reach to break condition.

Comment: This is not correct, age is changing in the loop so it will reach the break condition

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to change the condition of infinite iteration.

```
# while guess != age:
while True:
```

Comment: `while guess != age:` and `if age == guess:    break` is blatantly redundant. He can get rid of any of them. Anyway, this is not a recursion, it's an iteration.

Comment: @PacoAbato Representation was wrong. Thank you for the advice.